# RIGHT/LEFT OUTER JOIN and the missing values. MS-ACCESS SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Sorry I realized that my Table C was wrong. Below the updeted Table C
   
I need to generate a Table C like:
        Table C
          "Sector"  "BB_Allocation"           "totSum"                                  
            0       "North America"            "0,5"
            0       "Western Europe"           "0,5"
            0       "Asia Pacific"              ""
            0       "South & Central America"   ""
            0       "Africa / Middle East"      ""

 Taking the values form:

Table A
    "ID"    "isin"          "fldName"                           "blkName"           "fldValue"
    186999  "IE00B4WXJD03"  "HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION"  "North America"     "0,5"
    187000  "IE00B4WXJD03"  "HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION"  "Western Europe"    "0,5"
```

AND

```
Table B:

    "ID"  "Bloomb_Blk"                     "Bloomb_Allocation"      "BB_Allocation"
    1     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  North America            North America
    2     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  Western Europe           Western Europe
    3     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  Asia Pacific             Asia Pacific
    4     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  South & Central America  South & Central America
    5     HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION  Africa / Middle East     Africa / Middle East
    6     FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Government               Government
    7     FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Corporate                Corporate
    8     FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Mortgage                 Mortgage
    9     FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Preferred                Equity
    10    FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Municipal                Government
    11    FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Equity                   Equity
    12    FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC             Cash and Other           Cash and Other
```

I First tried with:

```
        strSQL = "SELECT 0 AS Sector, B.BB_Allocation, IIF(IsNull(Sum(CDbl(IIF(IsNull(fldValue), 0,fldValue)))),0,Sum(Format(CDbl(IIF(IsNull(fldValue), 0,fldValue))&'', '#,##0.00'))) AS totSum  " & _
        "FROM A as S " & _
        "RIGHT OUTER JOIN B AS B " & _
        "ON S.blkName=B.BB_Allocation " & _
        "WHERE " & _
        "(S.isin='" & Code & "' " & _
        "AND " & _
        "S.fldName='HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION' )" & _
        "GROUP BY B.BB_Allocation "
```

But I get only:

```
    "Sector"            "BB_Allocation"     "totSum"                    
    "0"                 "North America"     "0,5"
    "0"                 "Western Europe"    "0,5"
```

Then I tried to insert in the WHERE condition "OR S.fldName IS NULL", but then I got all B.BB_Allocation, instead I'm looking for all the HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION, not for the FUND_ASSET_ALLOC_CALC

Comment: Why is "4" repeated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

You seem to want to get all the `isin`s from the first table and ten all the geo country regions from the second.  That requires a `CROSS JOIN` (which MS Access implements using a `,`).  Then use `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the existing values:

```
select b.id, i.isin, Bloomb_Blk as fldName, b.Bloomb_Allocation as blkName, 
       a.fldValue
from ((select distinct isin from a) as i, b) left join
     a
     on b.Bloomb_Blk = a.fldName and
        b.Bloomb_Allocation = a.blkName
where b.Bloomb_Blk = "HB_GEO_COUNTRY_REGION_ALLOCATION"
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I realized that my question was not accurate, I want to get the updated Table C, with no Isin

Comment: @Giovanni . . .  In general, I don't play the game of "guess the question I really want".  The better approach is to ask a new question.  It is nice if you accept this answer, but you could also just delete this one.  Changing the question to invalidate answers can result in downvotes.